# Grab the content for a given request programmatically in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to grab the content that a Wordpress site would return for a particular request *programmatically* within the code.

In pseudo-code:

*my-wp-template.php*

```
request = get_the_request() // www.example.com/foo/bar

content = get_the_content(request) // the content returned if I were to go to www.example.com/foo/bar in the browser
```

Basically, its like a curl request but using Wordpress internals.

Why would you want to do this?

I am routing a request in the form `example.com/foo/bar` to *my-wp-template.php*.

I would like that template to function such that it returns the content for `exmaple.com/bar`, as if the request was made with no `/foo/` slug.

A redirect would *not* work in my use-case.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by first retrieving the post ID from the route you want to with [url_to_postid()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/), and then use that ID to get the content of this post/page using [get_the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/). This is how:

```
$content_of_foo_bar = get_the_content(null, false, url_to_postid( 'www.example.com/foo/bar' ));
```